# Constructing a pangenome graph using multiple samples

Tags: reference-genome, graphs, pangenome

I am working with yeast strains (specifically S. cerevisiae) that have been cultured and evolved over many generations in the lab. I am using the reference S288C strain when I do certain analyses but I want to be able to construct my own reference using the "in-house" strains. Ultimately I want to be able to call variants when mapping strains to this "in-house" reference to make it easier to visualize/understand the difference in strains.

I am trying to use [VG-tools](https://github.com/vgteam/vg) to create a pangenome graph using 10 different strains all sharing the same reference and I'm honestly a little confused on how to go about doing it. I was able to make a "vg" file for each sample individually but I know downstream I want to be able to map other strains to this pangenome as a reference and call variants to it rather than the standard reference sequence.

I'm mainly looking to see if anyone has built a "pangenome graph" using multiple samples and how they went about doing it. If anyone could give me some tips/tricks/advice for this kind of task that would be great!

I have a phylogenetic tree of all the strains but how would I use that to see the differences in variation?

Comment: Hi @rimo what do you mean by a "graph". In graph theory a "graph" is a network. If its a classical bivariate plot, what is the y-axis? Finally, what about simply doing a tree?

Comment: Could you post a tree - remove the taxa labels to ensure confidentiality - and I will tell you how to read it. The answer is in the tree. Where the SNPs are located is a different analysis BTW.

Comment: @M__ rimo is talking about a genome graph, like the example shown in the [vg repository](https://github.com/vgteam/vg#variation-graph-data-structures-interchange-formats-alignment-genotyping-and-variant-calling-methods)

Comment: @gringer I did raise this point originally. This is graph theory, but graph theory is based on trees (it provides the direction).